# Counting cells in Excel within date range but only when greater than cell above it

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet that displays weekly increases and decreases by percentage. I would like to count the number of times within a given year that a week's numbers increased by more than the week that preceded it, and only if the previous week's increase is at least 2%.

For example, in the following spreadsheet, the count should be 1 for 2010:

```
Date         Increase/Decrease %
12/28/2009   -3.1%
1/4/2010     1.2%
1/11/2010    2.0%
1/18/2010    2.1% (this is the one that should be counted)
1/25/2010    1.9% 
2/1/2010     2.5% (don't count because previous week did not meet 2% threshold)
```

Here's the formula I'm using to count the number of times a percentage increase is met, but I'm not sure how to add the condition that the following week must exceed the previous week's.

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$7,">"&.02,$A$2:$A$7,">"&"12/31/2009,$A$2:$A$7,"<"&"1/1/2011")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=SUMPRODUCT(-(B3:B7>B2:B6),-(B2:B6>=0.02),-(A3:A7>DATE(2009,12,31)),-(A3:A7<DATE(2011,1,1)))`

Or with BigBen's insight:

`=SUMPRODUCT((B3:B7>B2:B6)*(B2:B6>=0.02)*(YEAR(A3:A7)=2010))`

Comment: You could use `YEAR(A3:A7)=2010` to shorten it too - otherwise nice.